# Translation of "I have never been to ..."

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, word-choice

What would be the best translation for

> I have never been to Germany.

Would it be

> Ich bin noch nie nach Deutschland gegangen.

or

> Ich bin noch nie nach Deutschland gewesen.

?

Also, is the present perfect tense appropriate here?

Comment: this sentence is not finished or complete. Ich bin noch nie in Deutschland ? what, gewesen, gefragt worden, gestorben, betroffen gewesen ??? there is something missing here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPGEGxBI-Ko

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latter is more right, though it should be *in*, not *nach*, since there is no concept of movement involved in German:

> Ich bin noch nie in Deutschland gewesen.
>   Ich war noch nie in Deutschland.

As usual, perfect and preterite tenses are both possible, with preterite preferred in writing.

There is a famous song by [Udo Jürgens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udo_J%C3%BCrgens) called *Ich war noch niemals in New York*.

Comment: What about using the present tense `Ich bin noch nie in Deutschland`? Would this give an incorrect meaning?

Comment: @Mika H.: _Noch nie_ requires a past tense. You could say _Ich bin nie in Deutschland_, which has a different meaning (general habit of not being in Germany).